# Fixing holes going to the sides of concrete steps

Tags: concrete, repair, hole

I have some holes going through not the top, but the sides of my concrete steps. What can I use to back up the holes in order to be able to fill them in with some quick setting cement? And what sort of preparation do I need to do in order to make sure that the adhesion is correct?

Comment: Pictures would help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Just fill the whole thing with more concrete?

Answer (score 2):

Since you give absolutely no detail:

Either pack them full of a stiff mortar mix if they are small, or if they are huge, fill them with bricks or blocks and mortar. Clean out any loose material and wet the hole before applying mortar.